# create custom week variable based on cycle variable in R

Tags: r, date

I don't think this is so complicated but I'm getting lost in it.
I have a dataframe where I need to create a new column of weeks based on a cycle column. The problem is the number of cycles in week_0 varies between people (ID), and there are the same amount of days per week (7) for each following week (week_1 through week_6). So theoretically my data would look like this at the end:

```
| ID | cycle |  week   |
| 1  | 0     |  week_0 |
| 1  | 01    |  week_0 |
| 1  | 02    |  week_0 |
| 1  | 03    |  week_1 |
| 1  | 04    |  week_1 |
| 1  | 05    |  week_1 |
| 1  | 06    |  week_1 |
| 1  | 07    |  week_1 |
| 1  | 08    |  week_1 |
| 1  | 09    |  week_1 |
| 1  | 10    |  week_2 |
...
| 2  | 0     |  week_0 |
| 2  | 01    |  week_1 |
...
```

I've created a vector (diff_days) of the amount of days in week_0 per ID but can't figure out how to write the loop that would create my week variable and values based on `cycle[1] + diff_days`.

Basically I want:
if x in cycle is between 0 and the associated diff_days value (here for ID = 1, diff_days = 3), then "week_0" should appear in the week column, and for every 7 cycle numbers after that, the subsequent weeks (week_1, week_2, week_3, week_4, week_5, week_6) should appear. Here for ID = 1 it's week_1 for cycle = 03 through cycle = 09, then week_2 for cycle = 10 through cycle = 16 etc.

I would need something like:

```
 for (i in cycle) {
   if (i<= diff_days) {
     i <- "week_0"
   }
if (i>diff_days & i<=diff_days+7) {
i <- "week_1"
}
etc...
 }
```

I know this is not proper R syntax but I can't figure out how to translate it.

Or am I making my life way more complicated than it needs to be and there's an easy fix for this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: yes sorry about that

Here is the diff_days vector

```
c(4, 7, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 6, 6, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 3, 0, 6, 10, 0, 4, 
3, 4, 6, 3, 3, 12, 4, 5, 4, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 
-1, 5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7, 4, 4, 11, 6, 5, 6, 3)
```

and here are the first 60 rows from my dataframe

```
structure(list(ID = c("PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", 
"PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", 
"PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", 
"PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", 
"PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", 
"PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", 
"PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", 
"PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", "PTP0022", 
"PTP0022", "PTP0040", "PTP0040", "PTP0040", "PTP0040", "PTP0040", 
"PTP0040", "PTP0040", "PTP0040", "PTP0040", "PTP0040", "PTP0040", 
"PTP0040", "PTP0040"), cycle_number = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 
44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
"18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
"29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", 
"40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", 
"51"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you share the `dput` of minimal sample of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your data I create a sample `tibble` and here is the code do what you asking for using `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)

data <- tibble(ID = c(rep(1, 45), rep(2, 43)),
  cycle = c("0", paste0("0", seq(1, 44)), "0", paste0("0", seq(1, 42))),
  # here I include the diff_day you mentioned into the sample
  # if you can provide sample of your data it would be easier to replicate
  # your environment
  diff_day = c(rep(3, 45), rep(1, 43)))

data
#> # A tibble: 88 x 3
#>       ID cycle diff_day
#>    <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#>  1     1 0            3
#>  2     1 01           3
#>  3     1 02           3
#>  4     1 03           3
#>  5     1 04           3
#>  6     1 05           3
#>  7     1 06           3
#>  8     1 07           3
#>  9     1 08           3
#> 10     1 09           3
#> # … with 78 more rows

summary(data)
#>        ID           cycle              diff_day    
#>  Min.   :1.000   Length:88          Min.   :1.000  
#>  1st Qu.:1.000   Class :character   1st Qu.:1.000  
#>  Median :1.000   Mode  :character   Median :3.000  
#>  Mean   :1.489                      Mean   :2.023  
#>  3rd Qu.:2.000                      3rd Qu.:3.000  
#>  Max.   :2.000                      Max.   :3.000
```

And here is the solution

```r
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(group = if_else(as.numeric(cycle) < diff_day,
    "week_0", "week_number")) %>%
  mutate(week = if_else(group == "week_0", "week_0",
    paste0("week_", (as.numeric(cycle) - diff_day) %/% 7 + 1)))
```

And here is the full output

```r
#>    ID cycle diff_day       group   week
#> 1   1     0        3      week_0 week_0
#> 2   1    01        3      week_0 week_0
#> 3   1    02        3      week_0 week_0
#> 4   1    03        3 week_number week_1
#> 5   1    04        3 week_number week_1
#> 6   1    05        3 week_number week_1
#> 7   1    06        3 week_number week_1
#> 8   1    07        3 week_number week_1
#> 9   1    08        3 week_number week_1
#> 10  1    09        3 week_number week_1
#> 11  1   010        3 week_number week_2
#> 12  1   011        3 week_number week_2
#> 13  1   012        3 week_number week_2
#> 14  1   013        3 week_number week_2
#> 15  1   014        3 week_number week_2
#> 16  1   015        3 week_number week_2
#> 17  1   016        3 week_number week_2
#> 18  1   017        3 week_number week_3
#> 19  1   018        3 week_number week_3
#> 20  1   019        3 week_number week_3
#> 21  1   020        3 week_number week_3
#> 22  1   021        3 week_number week_3
#> 23  1   022        3 week_number week_3
#> 24  1   023        3 week_number week_3
#> 25  1   024        3 week_number week_4
#> 26  1   025        3 week_number week_4
#> 27  1   026        3 week_number week_4
#> 28  1   027        3 week_number week_4
#> 29  1   028        3 week_number week_4
#> 30  1   029        3 week_number week_4
#> 31  1   030        3 week_number week_4
#> 32  1   031        3 week_number week_5
#> 33  1   032        3 week_number week_5
#> 34  1   033        3 week_number week_5
#> 35  1   034        3 week_number week_5
#> 36  1   035        3 week_number week_5
#> 37  1   036        3 week_number week_5
#> 38  1   037        3 week_number week_5
#> 39  1   038        3 week_number week_6
#> 40  1   039        3 week_number week_6
#> 41  1   040        3 week_number week_6
#> 42  1   041        3 week_number week_6
#> 43  1   042        3 week_number week_6
#> 44  1   043        3 week_number week_6
#> 45  1   044        3 week_number week_6
#> 46  2     0        1      week_0 week_0
#> 47  2    01        1 week_number week_1
#> 48  2    02        1 week_number week_1
#> 49  2    03        1 week_number week_1
#> 50  2    04        1 week_number week_1
#> 51  2    05        1 week_number week_1
#> 52  2    06        1 week_number week_1
#> 53  2    07        1 week_number week_1
#> 54  2    08        1 week_number week_2
#> 55  2    09        1 week_number week_2
#> 56  2   010        1 week_number week_2
#> 57  2   011        1 week_number week_2
#> 58  2   012        1 week_number week_2
#> 59  2   013        1 week_number week_2
#> 60  2   014        1 week_number week_2
#> 61  2   015        1 week_number week_3
#> 62  2   016        1 week_number week_3
#> 63  2   017        1 week_number week_3
#> 64  2   018        1 week_number week_3
#> 65  2   019        1 week_number week_3
#> 66  2   020        1 week_number week_3
#> 67  2   021        1 week_number week_3
#> 68  2   022        1 week_number week_4
#> 69  2   023        1 week_number week_4
#> 70  2   024        1 week_number week_4
#> 71  2   025        1 week_number week_4
#> 72  2   026        1 week_number week_4
#> 73  2   027        1 week_number week_4
#> 74  2   028        1 week_number week_4
#> 75  2   029        1 week_number week_5
#> 76  2   030        1 week_number week_5
#> 77  2   031        1 week_number week_5
#> 78  2   032        1 week_number week_5
#> 79  2   033        1 week_number week_5
#> 80  2   034        1 week_number week_5
#> 81  2   035        1 week_number week_5
#> 82  2   036        1 week_number week_6
#> 83  2   037        1 week_number week_6
#> 84  2   038        1 week_number week_6
#> 85  2   039        1 week_number week_6
#> 86  2   040        1 week_number week_6
#> 87  2   041        1 week_number week_6
#> 88  2   042        1 week_number week_6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't shared your starting data, I'll assume from the phrasing of your question that you're starting with a dataframe of two columns (`ID, cycle`), and a separate vector `diff_days` containing diff days for each `ID`. Here are some simulated data for five IDs in this format as an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

cycledata <- tibble(
  ID = unlist(map(1:5, ~ rep(.x, 20))),
  cycle = rep(seq(from=0, to=19, by=1), 5)
)

diff_days <- c(3, 4, 2, 5, 6)
```

You can calculate the `week` column using a `case_when` function inside `mutate`, as below:

```
result <- cycledata %>%
  mutate(
    week = case_when(cycle < diff_days[ID] ~ paste0("week_0"),
                     TRUE ~ paste0("week_", floor((cycle-diff_days[ID]+7)/7)))
  )
```

The code above applies an if statement to each row in your dataframe. If the value of `cycle` is below the appropriate value of `diff_days`, it prints "week_0". If not, it uses a formula to calculate which other week the value of cycle belongs to.

Though my example assumes that each ID has 20 rows associated with it, this solution should work with uneven numbers of rows for each ID.